# Refresh/Reload web page only once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, page-refresh

I've searched high and low and am unable to find any scripts or instructions on how to have a page automatically refresh `ONLY ONCE` after initially being loaded/viewed.

I implemented a javascript code which states this: if the page is loaded completely, refresh the page immediately, but only once.

```
window.onload = function () {window.location.reload()}
```

But this gives a loop without the "only once".

I also Implemented `meta refresh` but it also gives a loop.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content= "0;URL=http://www.example.com" />
```

Please tell me how can i use body `onload` refresh functionality `only once` that is for first time and not every time the php page is refreshed .

I appreicate your immediate response. Thanks

Comment: In theory, I haven't tried it but you can make a loop that loops once... and then have the script run inside the loop? Just make sure you escape the loop afterwards and it won't re-loop inside

Comment: Why you need to reload the page???

Comment: @skibbi_bizzle, when the page is loaded completely. I want to refresh the page only once.

Comment: @RohitJindal — You were asked "Why" not "Please repeat yourself".

Comment: This is probably an X-Y problem where the solution to the actual problem is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should keep a flag in cookie, server session, or local storage. For example:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (! localStorage.justOnce) {
        localStorage.setItem("justOnce", "true");
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus 1, was going to suggest the local storage option, but this is a perfect alternative.

Comment: nice solution, i have never used `localStorage` so far. the only downside of it could be that you can't decide if you want the page to be reloaded only the first time you visit it - or if you want to reload it again if the user visits another page on your site. that's why i kinda like my solution with the GET var more.

Comment: How would you call this function?
    <script type="text/javascript">    
function initReload() {
window.onload = function () {
    if (! localStorage.justOnce) {
        localStorage.setItem("justOnce", "true");
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
}
</script>

<body onload="initReload()">

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you wanna do that. but you can just use php, javascript/jquery together to approach this:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET["reloaded"] != 1) { 

        echo '
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    window.location.href = "my_page.php?reloaded=1";
                });
            </script>
       '; 

    }
?>
```

explanation: when you load the page for the first time `$_GET["reloaded"]` is not set, so the javascript is echoed. i used jquery's document ready function here, to be sure that your DOM is fully loaded before it reloads the page. when reloading you set the GET variable `reloaded` to `1`.
thus php will not echo the javascript code again on reload.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set a cookie, to check if the user has refreshed or not. The following is basically pseudo-code for how you should do it.

Javascript

```
if(!COOKIE_EXISTS){
    SET_COOKIE();
    REDIRECT_TO_DESIRED_PAGE;
}
```

Php

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['page_was_refreshed'])){
    setcookie("CookieName", "CookieValue", time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    die(header("Location: your/url/to/redirect"));
}
```